# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar números finitos? (Java)

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo dos EditText en los que ingreso valores numéricos, el primer valor lo eleva al cuadrado y lo divide con el segundo, lo que me gustaría saber es cómo puedo hacer para mostrar números finitos, por ejemplo si la entrada es 10 y 33, la operación seria 100/33 = 3.0303030303... y me gustaría que mostrara como resultado 3.03 con una línea sobre la parte decimal.
(uso TextWatcher para disparar el metodo al momento de escribir siempre que ambos EditText tengan contenido

[image: Algo asi me gustaria que quedara]

```
text = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        VoltageC1 = et_voltage_c1.getText().toString();
        SegundoValorC1 = et_SegundoValor.getText().toString();

        if (!VoltageC1.isEmpty() && !SegundoValorC1.isEmpty()){
            tv_resistencia.setText(CalcularResistencia(VoltageC1, SegundoValorC1));
        }else {
            tv_resistencia.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};

et_voltage_c1.addTextChangedListener(text);
et_SegundoValor.addTextChangedListener(text);

rg_c1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId){
        case R.id.rb_potencia_c1_id:
            tv_title_SegundoVal.setText("Potencia");

            if (!VoltageC1.isEmpty() && !SegundoValorC1.isEmpty()){
                tv_resistencia.setText(CalcularResistencia(VoltageC1, SegundoValorC1));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rb_corriente_c1_id:
            tv_title_SegundoVal.setText("Corriente");

            if (!VoltageC1.isEmpty() && !SegundoValorC1.isEmpty()){
                tv_resistencia.setText(CalcularResistencia(VoltageC1, SegundoValorC1));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
});

    // Todo: Todo lo relacionado al calculo de voltaje

}

private String CalcularResistencia(String voltageC1, String segundoValorC1) {

    double db_voltage = Double.parseDouble(voltageC1);
    double db_SegundoValor = Double.parseDouble(segundoValorC1);
    double db_resultado = 0;

    if (rb_potencia_c1.isChecked()){
        db_resultado = Math.pow(db_voltage, 2)/db_SegundoValor;
    }else if (rb_corriente_c1.isChecked()){
        db_resultado = db_voltage/db_SegundoValor;
    }

    return String.valueOf(db_resultado);

}
```

Comment: Comparte el código que has intentado

Comment: lo que quieres es que se muestre una línea arriba de la parte decimal ?

Comment: Si, es precisamente lo que busco

Answer (score 0):

Usa esto para limitarlo a dos decimales

```
double numero = 3.030303;

DecimalFormat formato1 = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(formato1.format(numero)); // Resultado => 3,03
```

ahora si quieres que sea 3/03 solo combiertelo a String y remplaza el "." por "/"

```
System.out.println((formato1.format(numero) + "").replace(".", "/")); // Resultado => 3/03
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no es lo que busco